# Printing list of objects

Tags: c#

I have the below class, how do I print the list of objects in format [1,[2,3,8],[[]],10,[]] in C#?

```
public class InnerList
{
    private int val;
    private boolean isValue;
    private List<InnerList> intList;
}
public string ConvertToString()
{
    if (this.isValue)
    {
        return this.val + "";
    }
    else
    {
        return this.intList.ToString();
    }
}
```

In my caller, I will use something like below to print the list of objects in format [1,[2,3,8],[[]],10,[]]

```
System.out.println(list);
```

My question is how to achieve this in c#?

Comment: What is this "System.out.println()" ?

Comment: That means Console.WriteLine() in java as i remember. Yet I don't understand the main objective here

Comment: Can you please provide valid C# code as input that you want formatted as `[1,[2,3,8],[[]],10,[]]`?

Comment: The name of your `InnerList` is confusing. You should call it `InnerItem` or `Item` or something else that represents a single item.

Answer (score 1):

**[Solution:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RTgXSU)**

```
public class InnerList
{
    //public only for simple initialization at usage example
    public int val;
    public bool isValue;
    public List<InnerList> intList;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (isValue)            
            return val.ToString();                
        return String.Format("[{0}]", intList == null ? "" : String.Join(", ", intList.Select(x => x.ToString())));
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var test = new InnerList
{
    intList = new List<InnerList>  {
        new InnerList { isValue = true, val = 1 },
        new InnerList { isValue = true, val = 2 },
        new InnerList
        {
            intList = new List<InnerList>  {
                new InnerList { isValue = true, val = 13 },
                new InnerList { isValue = true, val = 23 },
                new InnerList()
            }
        }
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(test);//[1, 2, [13, 23, []]]
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just a suggestion - you can simplify your `return` down to `return String.Format("[{0}]", intList == null ? "" : String.Join(", ", intList.Select(x => x.ToString())));`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C# world!

I can't understand what you trying to do, but i can show you how we do in by C#:

```
  public class InnerList
    {
        public int Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.intList.Count;
            }
        }

        public bool HasValue { get; set; }

        private List<InnerList> intList;

        public static implicit operator string(InnerList list)
        {
            return list.ToString();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (this.HasValue)
            {
                return this.Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return this.intList.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might run into the problem of circular them references here. Because an `InnerList` could reference its own parent in its `intList`. That is why I would recommend a serializer to do the job for you. It knows how to handle these circular references. I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` here.

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings);
}
```